# X theme section image background not looking full in screen sizes larger than 1300px width

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

Hi I am using corner stone to edit my web site, in wordpress using X theme.

Everything looks great and find on all screen sizes except for those 1300px width and larger.

ON my front page I use background images on two separate sections and set the padding to a large amount of pxs to fill out. However on larger screen sizes the background images look very small.

To fix this I tried to use custom css

```
@media  (min-width:1300px){
.custom { padding:500px;

}
}
```

Yet nothing changes, any suggestions to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your wordpress dashboard go to Appearance > Customize > Layout & Design.
For Site Layout and Content Layout choose Full Width.  Under Site Max Width, drag the bar to the far right.  I believe the max is 1500px.  This should solve your problem.